# Changing the order of called functions randomly

Tags: python, random

I have a function whose outline is given below. In `main()`, I want to return the returned values of one of the functions but I want to choose it randomly. As of now, it checks `func1` first and proceeds only if `func1 is some_val`. I want to be able to check `func2` first sometimes as well.

I realize that I could call both functions, create a list with the outcomes, and randomly shuffle the list but both `func1` and `func2` are quite a bit involved, so performance is an issue.

Is there a clean way to do it?

```
def func1():
    
    ... do things
    
    return val

def func2():
    
    ... do things
    
    return val



def main():
    
    if func1() is not some_val:
        return func1()
    
    elif func2() is not some_val:
        return func2()
    
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: Shuffle a list of functions, not outcomes.

Comment: It's funny you mention that performance is an issue, because your current code will execute a function 2 times and possibly 3 times in case elif part is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shuffle the list of functions, then iterate over that list, calling them one at a time.

```
def main():
    functions = [func1, func2, func3]
    random.shuffle(functions)

    for f in functions:
        if (rv := f()) is not some_val:
            return rv
```

Note that this does require each function to have the same signature (and take the same arguments), but it is trivial to create a list of zero-argument functions that call the "real" functions with the appropriate arguments. E.g.,

```
functions = [lambda: func1(x, y), lambda: func2(z, "hi", 3.14)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import shuffle

def main(list_of_functions=[func1, func2], *args, **kwargs):
    shuffle(list_of_functions)
    outcomes = []
    for func in list_of_functions:
        outcomes.append(func(*args, **kwargs))
    return outcomes

main()
```

Assuming `func1()` returns `"hello"` and `func2()` returns `"world"`...

```
>>> main()
["hello", "world"]
>>> main()
["world", "hello"]
>>> main()
["world", "hello"]
```

Pretty simple. That's all you need to do. Functions can be stored as variables like this:

```
>>> def otherFunc():
...     print("hi")
...
>>> otherFunc()
hi
>>> someFunc = otherFunc
>>> someFunc()
hi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def f1():
    print(1)

def f2():
    print(2)

def f3():
    print(3)

listf=[f1,f2,f3]

for i in range(10):
    random_index = random.randrange(0,len(listf))
    listf[random_index]()
```

Result:

```
2
2
1
2
1
3
2
3
3
2
```